# How to ignore specific devices in gparted (or: only regard selected devices)

Tags: partition, gparted

Sometimes, I just need `GParted` for one specific device such as */dev/mmcblk0*.

But because `GParted` scans through **all devices,** I have to fight through some errors. Additionally, all HDD's spin up and every non-responsive device (i.e. reading through bad sectors with *`gddrescue`*) adds to the severe loading time.

Additionally, after each operation, the whole device list needs to be reloaded again, ditching me to fight through all these libParted errors again, and hoping not to write anything to /dev/sda1.

#### How do I make `gparted` only scan through specific devices instead of all devices?

If not `GParted`, is it possible with KDE partition manager at least?

Comment: It's in the manual... really... `gparted dev1 dev2 etc` e.g. in your case `gparted  /dev/mmcblk0`

Comment: @don_crissti Because I did not expect the manual to have a solution for that (some things are undocumented on other programs in my experience), I asked here. But if it is that simple, it could even have been guessed. I will try it.

Comment: @don_crissti It still shows “scanning all devices” in the bottom status bar. Can this scanning be skipped somehow (except for selected devices)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that here with v.`0.32.0`... it only says _"scanning /dev/sdd partitions"_ in the status bar (when invoked with `/dev/sdd` as the only argument)

Comment: Actually, only the selected device shows up in the device list, but _scanning all devices_ takes a long time